# Wired Network Issue with Debian based system booted on Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: linux, macos, debian, ethernet, wired-networking

I dual booted my mac with Parrot OS. I have perfectly fine wireless connection but Ethernet is not recognized. When I installed the system, it said that the Ethernet card could not be identified and asked me to choose one from the list. I thought I could probably just fix it later so I said no network. Is there any way to install the correct driver onto Parrot (which is Debian based)?

## Debian Outputs:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 6540  bytes 416615 (406.8 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6540  bytes 416615 (406.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 26:7e:42:4c:53:52  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 31337  bytes 31058922 (29.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 23980  bytes 5218400 (4.9 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 96:ab:7b:be:6b:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Additional debian outputs: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3DC1krGr)

## Mac Hardware Information

[USB Ethernet Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YiV4.png)

[iBridge Ethernet Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhap7.png)

`ioreg -p IOUSB:` [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DUCknByC)

`ioreg -c AppleUSBDevice -p IOUSB:` [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/b7YU7eSh)

Thanks

Comment: The problem is to identify the correct driver (and Mac often uses special hardware, so such a driver may not exist). First thing to look at is `lspci -nn` and `lsusb` to see if it's a PCI or USB based network card. Alternatively, boot into MacOS and identify the network hardware.

Comment: @dirkt I put the others here: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3DC1krGr)

Comment: I don't see any Ethernet hardware, so either it's behind Thunderbolt, or it's disabled by the BIOS. If you boot into MacOS and start the "System Information" app, as what does the Ethernet hardware identify? (Please edit question, comments are not guaranteed to stick around).

Comment: I see an iBridge card and a USB card. What information do you need?

Comment: iBridge is Apple internal. Please do `ioreg -p IOUSB` in a terminal and edit question with output, so we can see the hierarchy. Also do `ioreg -c AppleUSBDevice -p IOUSB`, find the Ethernet device (mine is called "USB 10/100/1000 LAN"), and edit question with the details for that device. My guess is still that it's behind Thunderbolt. Is this an external USB LAN device? If yes, how have you attached it?

Comment: @dirkt I do not have an external LAN device. I updated the information. Thanks so much btw.

Comment: I can't see the USB network in the `ioreg` tree, either. I don't really understand why it appears as an USB device in System Information. The only explanation left is that this is somehow a "fake" USB device that is in reality some other hardware. In that case, chances of finding a driver for it are next to zero.